# How to invoke a javascript constructor in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, azure-maps

I would like to develop a Blazor component to wrap Azure Maps javascript.
The first step is to display the map on the page.

Usually, with javascript, it is done this way :

```
let map = new atlas.Map('mapContainer', {
    view: 'Auto',
    maxZoom:22,
    zoom:4,
    center: [2.35405, 43.855103],
    style:'road',
    showLogo:false,
    showFeedbackLink:false,                        
    authOptions: {
        authType:atlas.AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
        subscriptionKey: <subscriptionKey>
    }
});
```

With Blazor, JS cannot be directly handle this way. So, I have to use JSRuntime to write this code :

```
mapsModule = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js");
    
// The following is using custom c# code
MapAuthOptions authOptions = new MapAuthOptions();
authOptions.subscriptionKey = this.subscriptionKey;
authOptions.authType = AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey;
    
MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
options.authOptions = authOptions;
options.showFeedbackLink = false;
options.showLogo = false;
options.maxZoom = 22;
options.zoom = 4;
options.view = "Auto";
options.style = "road";
    
// this line crash
await mapsModule.InvokeAsync<object>("atlas.Map", "mapContainer", options);
```

I wonder how to call classic JS constructor. To be more precise, how to call **new atlas.Map()** with InvokeAsync and **Blazor** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been developing such a solution for a couple of months now. You can take a look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/AzureMapsControl.Components) and use this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureMapsControl.Components/).

My decision to create a new instance of map was basically to expose a static method which would create the map. Something like that in typescript :

```js
public static addMap(mapId: string,
        configuration: Configuration,
        serviceOptions: azmaps.ServiceOptions,
        enabledEvents: string[],
        eventHelper: EventHelper<MapEventArgs>): void {
...
        const map = new azmaps.Map(mapId, serviceOptions);
...
```

Basically I wrap the calls to the `atlas` library into static methods.

After that, the calls to your scripts are quite easy using your instance of `IJsRuntime` :

```cs
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(Constants.JsConstants.Methods.Core.AddMap.ToCoreNamespace(),
                Id,
                Configuration.Value,
                ServiceOptions,
                enabledEvents,
                DotNetObjectReference.Create(_mapEventInvokeHelper));
```

Comment: Merci Arnaud :)

Comment: I'm using this library and it's great, but I'm struggling to render more than 1 map at a time on the screen. When I try to render, let's say 3, only 1 will ever render and it seems like a race condition as to which one wins. Is this a limitation?

Comment: It currently only supports one map. This is something I have on my backlog, but I currently don't find any time to work on this library.